# Loading angular components depending upon configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-components

I'm trying to create a dashboard using Angular 5 , I have created few components that display data , and I'm bootstrapping them , and they call in services , and display data accordingly , now the problem is , I don't want to load all widgets by bootstrapping them , before the app bootstraps , I want to call a service , which will give an array of components that need to be loaded and I would like to bootstrap only those , I gave a shot at APP_INITIALIZER function , I'm able to call the service that gives the config array , but I'm not sure on how to make it populate the entryComponent array in app.module.ts ,

This is what I have tried , the componentConfigService is printing the jsonConfigResponse before components are loaded .

```
     @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        comp1,
        comp2,
        comp3
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [comp1Service , ComponentConfigService,
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: (configService: ComponentConfigService) => function() { return configService.getWidgetsToLoad()},
          deps: [ComponentConfigService],
          multi: true
        }],
      entryComponents: [],
      bootstrap: [Comp1,comp2]
})
```

I need help in knowing how I'll be able to read config before bootstrapping and populate entryComponent[] so that only those elements get bootstrapped and displayed

ex: A , B , C , D are components 
    Configuration before bootstrapping returns an array with only {B,D}
    so only B & D get bootstrapped and displayed in page .

Thanks in advance for your responses .

Answer (score 0):

We're also researching in similar paths and trying to achieve the same!

Since **entryComponents** array has to be populated before the build, it may not be possible to load the array with the service.

Moreover, this data has to be populated before the build to make the AOT work!

If we progress anything on this, will keep you posted!

Comment: Thank you , and so will I .